# Creating a DynamoDB table in Cloudformation fails

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I'm getting the following error:

> Property AttributeDefinitions is inconsistent with the KeySchema of the table and the secondary indexes

But I'm not sure whats wrong here.

```
  FeedbackTable: 
    Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
    Properties: 
      AttributeDefinitions: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "uuid"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "timestamp"
          AttributeType: "N"
        - 
          AttributeName: "pros"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "cons"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "comments"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "options"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "luaA"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "luaB"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "luaC"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "uuid"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        - 
          AttributeName: "timestamp"
          KeyType: "RANGE"
      ProvisionedThroughput: 
        ReadCapacityUnits: "1"
        WriteCapacityUnits: "1"
      TableName: "BD_Feedback"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to specify all attributes for the DynamoDB table here. What cloudformation requires are definitions for key and index attributes only.

So if you reduce you AttributeDefinition to `uuid` and `timestamp`, it should be fine (as long as you have no secondary indices).

Here the section from the CloudFormation docs on this topic:

> A list of attributes that describe the key schema for the table and
>   indexes. Duplicates are allowed.

[CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#cfn-dynamodb-table-attributedef)